# How does Google create such professionally-looking screen recording GIFs?

Tags: software-recommendation, gif, screenshot

Recently, I have come across this screen recording from a Google blog:

[image]

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/03/set-start-times-and-import-reminders-in.html

Notice how the mouse pointer moves in straight lines and perfectly accelerated and decelerated. Also, note the zooming in and out.

To me, it looks like all mouse actions were captured, restricted to essentials (mouse clicks), then interpolated (straight motion between clicks), and then replayed and the screen captured.

What tools are available to create screen recordings such as these?

Comment: Regarding the fact that this is not regular mouse icon AND that when you use calendar it change to "hand" when clicking on "tasks" and small calendar I would say it something done in postprocessing.

Comment: visual style looks a lot like what I get out of Screenflow.

Comment: @GerardFalla yes, I agree, compare https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewTB56bEU3g. Unfortunately, Mac-only, but thanks anway!

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [Adobe Captivate](https://www.adobe.com/se/products/captivate.html). It seems to be able to do what you are looking for.
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hjkLhWuWAY) is an example cursor movement editing.